# Appendices in tables of contents under Appendices section

Tags: appendices

I have a very simple article which consists of the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{appendix}

\begin{document} 
\tableofcontents

\appendixtitleon
\appendixtitletocon
\section{Writing}
\begin{appendices}
\section{First appendix}
\subsection{First}
\subsection{Second}
\section{Second appendix}
\subsection{First}
\subsection{Second}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

This produces the following output:[image]

This is almost what I want, except, I actually want the appendices to come under an appendices section in the table of contents (everything indented a level so to speak). The output would be like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add the `[toc]` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[toc]{appendix}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\appendixtitleon
\appendixtitletocon
\section{Writing}
\begin{appendices}
\section{First appendix}
\subsection{First}
\subsection{Second}
\section{Second appendix}
\subsection{First}
\subsection{Second}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried this, doesn't this add them as sections? They are not under the Appendices section, they are just listed below them?

Comment: I dont' really understand what you mean. `Appendix A`, `Appendix B` *are* sections. The `[toc]` just adds an intertitle, just to  say: here begins the appendices part.

Comment: Yeah that wasn't very clear. What I'm looking for is the appendix section to exist in the table of contents, but with each appendix being a subsection (I'm not sure if that is right). So the indent is something like the provided output.

Comment: I think it  should be possible to leave each appendix as a section, but have a subsection layout in the table of contents with `titletoc` and `apptools`.